# How can I make this link inside of a php plugin open in a new window popup

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, popup, window

I have this code for pinterest which I want to open in a popup window:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.get_permalink().'&media='.wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ).'&description='.get_the_title(  $post->ID ).'" class="sharebtn_pinterest" count-layout="horizontal"></a>';
```

It is a plugin for WordPress that I am editing.

**Edit:** Here is the code I would like to work but no popup opens

```
 {
    echo '<div class="bla"> 
    <a onClick="MyWindow=window.open("http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.get_permalink().'&media='.wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ).'&description='.get_the_title(  $post->ID ).',"MyWindow","width=600,height=500") class="sharebtn_pinterest" "/></a></div>';
}
```

Comment: What does it do now? The `target="_blank"` bit should already open it in a new tab/window.

Comment: just updated the code so you can see what i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Some javascript to add:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}

// -->
</script>
```

Edit your link to:

```
<a onclick="return popitup("http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.get_permalink().'&media='.wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ).'&description='.get_the_title(  $post->ID ).'")"
    >Link to popup</a>
```

Copied from [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html). 1st result. Did you try searching this on Google first?

Comment: no does not work if i insert the javascript function into the wordpress plugin it will not activate

Comment: if i insert into the head it does not see that either

Comment: @djbridger - Please do not append non-working code to existing "answers". Just [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13954241/edit) and add any additional information. (Edit: Never mind, I see you figured it out :)

Comment: sorry i am getting used to this site still, no i an still beaten by this and struggling

Comment: Yep, it is an "answer" all right. The question and the amount of detail gave me nothing to go on, at first.

Comment: djbidger, Again, did you Google? I know naught about Wordpress so I copy pasted the code directly. But apparently in WP you need to use wp_enqueue_script() to add JavaScript. Check [this link](http://planetozh.com/blog/2008/04/how-to-load-javascript-with-your-wordpress-plugin/) out.

Comment: Google for mw is always the 1st option to find help in a forum is always the last option, i have spent nearly 2 days on google trying code and nothing has worked yet.